# Chrome Node inspector causes code to execute differently?

Tags: node.js, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, node-inspector

I'm running into a strange problem where some code takes different paths depending on whether Chrome devtools is open or not.. or at least it seems that way.

**Example**

`Transaction` is just a simple Mongoose Model. I'm using MongoDB Atlas.

```
import Transaction from '../models/Transaction'

export default async function sendMessage({ textMsg, recipient, event }) {
  
  debugger;
  // pause here to inspect DB

  try {
    const { transactionHash } = event
    // transactionHash is a string
    const existingTx = await Transaction.exists({ transactionHash })
   
    // don't want dupe transactions, check if hacker is trying `replay` an old transaction..
    if (existingTx) {
      console.log('This transaction has already happened')
      // tx was already sent, early return..
      return
    }

    const transactionRecord = new Transaction({textMsg, recipient})
    await transactionRecord.save()
    
   ... Else send the message..
```

*This is a function that is called in a routeHandler.*

But something weird happens when I run the Node/ExpressJS server with `--inspect` and open the Chrome Node inspector devtools: By the time the inspector pauses at line 1 (the `debugger;` statement) a Mongo record for Transaction (transactionHash) is already created. It doesn't even hit the line where `transactionRecord.save()` sits. Thus, `existingTx` always returns true and the function early returns.

**This doesn't happen when Node debugger is closed**

Running node with `--inspect` ***but not opening*** Chrome Node inspector devtools **never early returns**. The `existingTx` variables returns false, it doesn't early return, a mongo record is saved, and a message is sent (the final goal of the function).

**Why does it do this?**
I've been racking my brains as to why this is. I was thinking it was a sourcemaps problem, but even a sourcemaps problem wouldn't cause the code to take different paths.

Has any ever run into something similar?

Comment: What about with `--inspect-break`? That should force execution to stop before anything starts which should let the breakpoint get added in time.

Comment: But, `transactionHash` was passed into the function already as `event.transactionHash` so, as a value or object (whatever it is), it already exists before the function event starts to execute.  Be aware that breakpoints can cause a significant difference in the relative timing between different asynchronous operations because asynchronous operations that are running in native code are not paused by the debugger.

Comment: `transactionHash` is a string in this case (unique hash created by Ethereum). The actual Mongo record shouldn't be created until `transactionRecord.save()` line. The `transactionRecord.save()` line is the only place any Mongo `save()` is called. So I'm baffled at why it gets created in line 1.

Comment: Put a `console.log()` statement right after your `debugger;` statement and right before and after your `transactionRecord.save()` call to see what is actually getting executed before you hit the debugger.